# DNIe 3.0 PROTOCOLO PACE BouncyCastle

Tags: java

En este documento (https://www.dnielectronico.es/PDFs/Manual_de_Comandos_para_Desarrolladores_102.pdf) hay una guía de como establecer la comunicación mediante un canal seguro sin contacto, es decir, deslizando la tarjeta por el NFC sin tener que introducirla. En los nuevos dnie (3.0) se utiliza el protocolo PACE para establecer este canal. En uno de los pasos, envío la clave pública del terminal para que el DNI me devuelva su clave pública y a continuación tengo que aplicar ECDH con mic lave privada y su clave pública. El caso es que cuando ejecuto el siguiente código me devuelve el error que muestro a continuación.

Código:

```
 public static void ecdh(String pukCardDH1, MyKeyPar ourClaves) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchProviderException, Exception{
    KeyAgreement ka = KeyAgreement.getInstance("ECDH", "BC");
    ka.init(loadPrivateKey(ourClaves.getPrivateKeyB()));
    ka.doPhase(loadPublicKey(EncriptacionAES128.hexStringToByteArray(pukCardDH1)), true);
    byte [] secret = ka.generateSecret();
    System.out.println("Secret key: " + EncriptacionAES128.byteArrayToHex(secret));
```

}

```
public static PublicKey loadPublicKey (byte [] data) throws Exception
{
            ECParameterSpec params = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec("brainpoolP256r1");
    ECPublicKeySpec pubKey = new ECPublicKeySpec(
            params.getCurve().decodePoint(data), params);
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("ECDH", "SÍ  ");
    return kf.generatePublic(pubKey);
}
public static PrivateKey loadPrivateKey (byte [] data) throws Exception
{
            ECParameterSpec params = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec("brainpoolP256r1");     
            ECPrivateKeySpec prvkey = new ECPrivateKeySpec(new BigInteger(data), params);
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("ECDH", "BC");
    return kf.generatePrivate(prvkey);
}
```

Y el error es el siguiente:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid point encoding 0x-66
    at org.bouncycastle.math.ec.ECCurve.decodePoint(Unknown Source)
```

En esta línea:

ECPublicKeySpec pubKey = new ECPublicKeySpec(
                params.getCurve().decodePoint(data), params);

El caso es que no se que codificación utiliza el DNI para mandar su clave.

Muchas gracias, 
Un saludo, 
Laura.